# Unable to set variables inside for loop with delayed expansion

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The code loops through the subfolders (`q1`, `q2`, etc.) under the directory. For each subfolder, there is another **for** loop to set several variables. I echoed several times. The first **for** loop works fine, I can see it goes through every subfolder. The problem is the code only set variables in the last subfolder, say `q100`. Now, I put the code line by line in cmd.

I tried `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. But I couldn't see that it works. I sincerely look for some help!

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %f in ('dir /ad /b ') do (
    echo %f
    pause
    pushd %f
    for /d "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %a in ('dir /b *.a*.dat in %f' ) do (
        set COM_DATA=%a
        echo %COM_DATA%
        set COM_V=%f\com-v.dat
        echo %COM_V%
        set COM_M=%f\com-M.dat
        echo %COM_M%
    )
    chdir
    popd
)
endlocal
```

The output I expected is in `q1` subfolder, `COM_DATA=q1.dat`, in `q2` subfolder, `COM_DATA=q2.dat`, etc.
The name of `com_v` and `com_M` are same in `q1`, `q2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've enabled delayed expansion, but you aren't using it. To use a variable with delayed expansion, you need to use `!` instead of `%`.

Also, for loop variables inside of scripts need *two* `%`s.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b ') do (
    echo %%f
    pause
    pushd %%f
    for /d "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b *.a*.dat in %%f' ) do (
        set COM_DATA=%%a
        echo !COM_DATA!
        set COM_V=%%f\com-v.dat
        echo !COM_V!
        set COM_M=%%f\com-M.dat
        echo !COM_M!
    )
    chdir
    popd
)
endlocal
```